# Django: check cookie on every page?

Tags: django, session, cookies

In Django: what's the best way to check whether a cookie is set before loading every page?

Background: I'm working with a site that uses LDAP auth. I want to avoid having to ask for`request.META.get('REMOTE_USER')` on every single page, because it absolutely hammers the server: it's requested for every resource on the page, the server gets tied up, falls back to Basic auth and the user sees lots of dialogs.

Therefore, I would like to do the following on every page in the site:

- check if a user cookie is set
- if not, redirect to a page that consists of just one HTML file, that asks for `REMOTE_USER` and saves it in a session-length cookie, then redirect back again.

Basically, I want an approximation of the @login_required decorator, without actually using the Django login/user framework.

Any suggestions for the nicest way to do this for all pages in the site, without repeating lots of code?

many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add a middleware, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request. Return a http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect if the cookie is not set, None if it's set.

Comment: Was going to post exactly the same thing. Middleware is the way to go.